# telegram bots : There is a way to find the IP or IP server administrator robot robots telegram?

Tags: telegram-bot

There is a way to find the IP or IP server administrator robot robots telegram?

I was entering a command to be achieved. Is this true?

Comment: I don't think it is clear what you are asking. Would you clarify?

Answer (score 3):

Sorry you can't ;)
Telegram server don't let you know about IP information of user.